# Refactoring JOLT code to get expected output

Tags: json, jolt

I have this input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "05301",
    "nome": "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
    "UF": {
      "id": 35,
      "sigla": "SP",
      "nome": "São Paulo",
      "regiao": {
        "id": 3,
        "sigla": "SE",
        "nome": "Sudeste"
      }
    },
    "sub-regioes-metropolitanas": [
      {
        "id": "0530101",
        "nome": "Sub-região 1",
        "municipios": [
          {
            "id": 3500758,
            "nome": "Alambari"
          },
          {
            "id": 3507001,
            "nome": "Boituva"
          },
          {
            "id": 3510302,
            "nome": "Capela do Alto"
          },
          {
            "id": 3511508,
            "nome": "Cerquilho"
          },
          {
            "id": 3511607,
            "nome": "Cesário Lange"
          },
          {
            "id": 3522307,
            "nome": "Itapetininga"
          },
          {
            "id": 3525854,
            "nome": "Jumirim"
          },
          {
            "id": 3551108,
            "nome": "Sarapuí"
          },
          {
            "id": 3554003,
            "nome": "Tatuí"
          },
          {
            "id": 3554508,
            "nome": "Tietê"
          }
        ]
      }]},
  {
    "id": "05101",
    "nome": "Região Metropolitana de Campinas",
    "UF": {
      "id": 35,
      "sigla": "SP",
      "nome": "São Paulo",
      "regiao": {
        "id": 3,
        "sigla": "SE",
        "nome": "Sudeste"
      }
    },
    "sub-regioes-metropolitanas": [],
    "municipios": [
      {
        "id": 3501608,
        "nome": "Americana"
      },
      {
        "id": 3503802,
        "nome": "Artur Nogueira"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need this output:

```json
[ [ {
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3500758,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3507001,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3510302,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3511508,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3511607,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3522307,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3525854,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3551108,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3554003,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05301",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Sorocaba",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "0530101",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "Sub-região 1",
  "id_mcpo" : 3554508,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05101",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Campinas",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "",
  "id_mcpo" : 3501608,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
},
{
  "id_rgia_mptn" : "05101",
  "nome_rgia_mptn" : "Região Metropolitana de Campinas",
  "id_sub_rgia_mptn" : "",
  "nome_sub_rgia_mptn" : "",
  "id_mcpo" : 3503802,
  "id_uf" : 35,
  "sgla_uf" : "SP",
  "id_rgia" : 3,
  "sgla_rgia" : "SE"
}]]
```

I tried with this JOLT and I didn't get the expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].id_rgia_mptn",
        "nome": "[&1].nome_rgia_mptn",
        "sub-regioes-metropolitanas": {
          "*": {
            "id": "[&1].id_sub_rgia_mptn",
            "nome": "[&1].nome_sub_rgia_mptn",
            "municipios": {
              "*": {
                "id": "[&3].id_mcpo"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "UF": {
          "id": "[&2].id_uf",
          "sigla": "[&2].sgla_uf",
          "regiao": {
            "id": "[&3].id_rgia",
            "sigla": "[&3].sgla_rgia"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add more identifier those will represent the indexes of the respective arrays from different levels in order to partition more while handling the issue dynamically after labeling each group by differently(`others` and `Main`) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.others.&_rgia_mptn",
        "municipios": {
          "*": {
            "id": "&3.Main[&1].&_mcpo"
          }
        },
        "sub-regioes-metropolitanas": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&1.others.&_sub_rgia_mptn",
            "municipios": {
              "*": {
                "id": "&3.Main[&1].id_mcpo"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "UF": {
          "id": "&2.others.&_uf",
          "*i*": "&2.others.&(0,1)&(0,2)_uf",
          "*e*o": {
            "id": "&3.others.&_&(1,1)&(1,2)",
            "*i*": "&3.others.&(0,1)&(0,2)_&(1,1)&(1,2)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Main": {
          "*": {
            "@2,others": {
              "*": "&4_&2.&"
            }, // go two levels up the tree to grab the values of the "others" array
            "*": "&3_&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Perfect! I've understood this and used the same specification to another file/JSON.
Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @MateusCostaLuz nice to help

Comment: I have a problem, when I use the same JOLT expression for a larger file, it stops working.
I tried to use the expression you sent me in this file, which is the original file with the final result for all sub-regions of Brazil.
It's the same as the template I sent you, but for some reason JOLT can't run it for all objects.
[link](https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/33/regioes-metropolitanas)
This example is the actual JSON I'm using to get the data.

Comment: I'm not talking about the limitation of the tool, but rather the conversion using JOLT in Java or through NiFi, it seems to stop working. Unfortunately [link](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) is unable to perform the conversion to test on something with many lines. Could you help me get the correct result, as you sent me, for the entire file?

Comment: Hi @MateusCostaLuz , the result is as expected : seven attributes return  instead of nine per each object. Since `"sub-regioes-metropolitanas"`  array has no value in the new JSON value you've posted

Comment: When I try using NiFi or Java/Scala, for some reason the JOLT are returning wrong structure result. I'm not understanding WHY. Can you help me, please?
Use the complete JSON located at [COMPLETE REGIOES JSON](https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/33/regioes-metropolitanas).

Could you try this full JSON using a language or NiFi?

The JSON is too large to test on the Jolt Transform Demo site.

Comment: @MateusCostaLuz Because the first shift transformation spec has a look for the `"sub-regioes-metropolitanas"` array but it has no content ( appear as `"sub-regioes-metropolitanas": []` ). Btw, this shared JSON fits within the input area of the Jolt Transform Demo site, no problem.

Comment: I want it according to these notes:
1. - "id" of each object belonging to the root list
2. - "name" of each object belonging to the root list
3. - "id" of each object belonging to the list of "sub-regioes-metropolitanas"
4. - "name" of each object belonging to the list of "sub-regioes-metropolitanas"
5. - "id" of each municipality belonging to the list of "municipios" belonging to the list of "sub-regioes-metropolitanas"

Comment: Like that:
1. root.id         -> id_rgia_mptn
2. root.nome        -> nome_rgia_mptn
3. root.sub-regioes-metropolitanas.id   -> id_sub_rgia_mptn
4. root.sub-regioes-metropolitanas.nome  -> nome_sub_rgia_mptn
5. root.sub-regioes-metropolitanas.municipios.id -> id_mcpo

Can you help me do a JOLT to get the expected result?